# If $M_{\alpha\beta}\ge0$ , how to show $M^\#\ge0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

We say $M_{\alpha\beta}\ge0$ if $M_{\alpha\beta}v^\alpha v^\beta\ge0$ (sum over $\alpha,\beta$) for all vectors $v=\{v^\alpha\}$.

If $M_{\alpha\beta}\ge0$ ,how to show 
$$
M^\#\ge0 ~?
$$

Relative define is in the below picture. The picture blow is from the 186-188 and 212 of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).If there are some details be missed,please tell me, I will add it.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M : \wedge^2 V\otimes_S \wedge^2 V\rightarrow {\bf R} $ so that there exists a basis $\{\phi_i\}$ which diagonalize $M$

So $$v=v^a\phi_a,\ M^\sharp (v,v)= v^a v^bC^{cd}_a C^{ef}_b M_{ce} M_{df} $$

$$ =    v^a v^bC^{cd}_a C^{cd}_b M_{cc} M_{dd} =( v^a C^{cd}_a)^2 M_{cc}M_{dd} \geq 0 $$

Comment: If the manifold is $n-dim$, is the sum over $\alpha$ from 1 to $n(n-1)/2$ ? I mean whether the $v$ is element of dual space of $\wedge^2 V$?

Comment: (1) Yes you are right (2) $v=v^a\phi_a$ is a vector That is $M=M_{ab} \phi_a^\ast \otimes \phi_b^\ast$